# Button unresponsive with .Net 4 Calendar (bug?)

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm in the latter stages of a project and I have a screen with a (customised .net4) calendar and a (again custom) button.

whenever a date is selected, the button becomes dormant, it will not switch to hover visual state and doesn't register it's first click. Once it is clicked however, it returns to being a normal button, firing commands, switching visual state, etc, at least until you change your mind about the date again..

My initial ideas were around focus, assuming there was a focusscope between the calendar and button or something similar, admittedly I'm not too hot on WPF focus, but haven't found any support for the theory yet.

I've managed to repeat it with this (tested in kaxaml):

```
  <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Calendar />
    <Button>Hello, world!</Button>
  </StackPanel>
```

and it's the same with the WPF Toolkit (Feb 2010) Calendar..

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, although I'm testing with buttons, I haven't found a UI element this doesn't work with, selecting a calendarDayButton will even make Kaxamls UI go dormant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Calendar` control appears to capture the mouse when clicked. You can get rid of this behavior by releasing the Mouse capture in the `GotMouseCapture` event.

No idea what the side effects of doing this are, but the code to release capture looks like this:

```
private void Calendar_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is CalendarItem)
        Mouse.Capture(null);
}
```

**Edit**

Was testing why releasing the mouse was causing navigation to stop working, and after some testing discovered that clicking certain items on a Calendar will capture focus, while others do not. The items that steal the mouse always have an `e.OriginalSource` of `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.CalendarItem`, so added a check to only release mouse capture if `e.OriginalSource` is of type `CalendarItem`

Comment: good find, works great for the CalendarDayButtons, but the calendar navigation buttons don't work. I've written a MEGA hack which just waits for 300ms before releasing mouse capture.. and that gets the navigation back up. Gonna keep looking for a clean sln =]

Comment: @Dead.Rabit I was looking into it a bit more and it turns out the Calendar control is actually a Popup. On click it captures the mouse, and to make it lose focus you have to click outside of it. Perhaps you could use a `DatePicker` instead of a `Calendar` which has a drop-down calendar and behaves like a ComboBox?

Comment: @Dead.Rabit See my update. It should allow you to navigate your `Calendar` correctly while still preventing it from stealing mouse events.